# Disabled Adapter sharing accidentally in Hyper-V on S2008R2 Std

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

A friend of mine with whom I share a dedicated server decided he'd play smart and install Hyper-V and try make some VMs, yeah that's all fine and dandy, until I watch him untick the "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" box then click Apply and, yea...

I don't have KVM to the dedi in question, however I am able to netboot WinPE - I am hoping this will suffice in being able to restore the adapter sharing setting?

Answer (score 2):

So it took some determination but I had a play around within regedit using WinPE and I got it to work with the following (this excludes most of my 'playaround research' and gets straight to a resolution for others encountering the same problem:
1) You need to identify what your Adapter's ClassGUID is, which can be obtained in a choice of ways:
1.A) Search the name you gave your 'Virtual Network' in the 'Virtual Network Manager' - this will find several results but you need to keep going until you land at your VMS_MP Registry Key.
1.B) Search for your 'VMS_MP' registry key, which should put you somewhere near *\Enum\Root\VMS_MP
2) Expand the VMS_MP registry key and click on any of the sub-entries, we're then interested in a REG_SZ called 'ClassGUID'.
3) After you have found your 'ClassGUID' you need to right-click>Modify>Ctrl+C it and then do Ctrl+F and paste it, then go back to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE root key, and press F3.
4) This should land you somewhere inside of *\Control\Class[YOUR CLASSGUID HERE] - expand the key and look through the sub-keys until you find the one with a REG_SZ Value called 'DriverDesc' and a 'Data' value of the name of your server's Network Interface Card. In my case it was 0007.
5) Open the relevant key and go to the 'Linkage' key. You now need to Right-click>Modify on the 'UpperBind' Value (which should contain something like 'VMSP' or 'VMSMP'), and change the contents to the following:
 Ndisuio RasPppoe rspndr lltdio Tcpip Tcpip6

Apply the above change, and then you can restart your server and allow it to boot up into Windows Server.

*Please note that this guide is provided as-is, and though this process worked for me I make no guarantee that it will resolve the problem for you. Also, this guide assumes that you know how to mount your system's registry, this is necessary to follow these instructions, see [here](https://community.landesk.com/support/docs/DOC-10928) for help on how to do this (you only need to mount the SYSTEM hive).*

Comment: Sorry I gave you an incorrect answer. I didn't realize you still had a network connection to remotely administer the machine.

Comment: Unfortunate this happened to me and I have no WinPE :( Luckily I could buy a IP-KVM for a day.